# Can i use GPS Garmin GPSmap 62s in GIS projects with high accuracy?

Tags: gps, garmin

i have GPS Garmin GPSmap 62s, is this can be dependable in GIS projects with high accuracy, and what is the "RMS", the minimum error rate in meter, and can i linking it with arcpad to draw road or buildings with high accuracy.

Comment: What do you consider "high accuracy"? RMS will change based on the day, weather, location, etc.  Consumer grade GPS is usually capable of 1-5 meter accuracy in good conditions.  Sub-meter not so much. Not sure how you would transfer your data to ArcPad. Depends on what device you have ArcPad on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't expect high accuracy from a handheld GPS. It has 3 meters error approximately. It can be linked to arcpad. Accuracy definition depends upon your application.